# Array of objects in Swing

Tags: java, swing, jlabel

So i got an array of objects.

my current code to show them now is in a JLabel that looks like this

```
public void setLblEvents(Calendar[] calendars) {

        String result = "";
for(int i = 0; i< calendars.length; i++)
{
    result += (+i +calendars[i].getTitle());
    result += (+i +calendars[i].getStartDate());
    result += (+i +calendars[i].getEndDate());
    result += (+i +calendars[i].getNote());
    result += (+i +calendars[i].getLocation());
}

lblEvents.setText(result);

}
```

This outputs all titles, all startdates and so on, in 1 line of text in my jlabel.

how would i display this in a pretty way, the most simple way.

Comment: Add `"\n"` where you want line breaks?

Comment: Use a `JList` in combination with a decent renderer ? Use HTML ? Depends a bit on what you want to do with it afterwards

Comment: I would use a `JTable`. Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [How to Use Tables](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html) for more information and examples.

Answer (score 0):

To show text on label in multiple lines, you would need to do something like the following,

```
String result = "<html>";
for(int i = 0; i< calendars.length; i++){
    result += (+i +calendars[i].getTitle()+"<br>");
    result += (+i +calendars[i].getStartDate()+"<br>");
    result += (+i +calendars[i].getEndDate()+"<br>");
    result += (+i +calendars[i].getNote()+"<br>");
    result += (+i +calendars[i].getLocation());
}

result += "</html>"

lblEvents.setText(result);
```